# Insert into X coordinate separately?

Tags: postgis

I have a postgis table with a point geometry for lat/long but i want to run a query that inserts a new row with lat, long values separately instead of concatenating them into a geometry.

so is there a way to insert the X and Y values separately ?

Comment: As separate columns aka attribute data? Or do you want to update the geometry coordinates separately?

Comment: I want to update the coordinates of the geometry separately while doing an INSERT command.

Comment: I am still confused about what you really want to do. You use the word update and insert together. That doesn't make sense. If you insert you add a new row (with the same data types as the other rows in the table). If you update you change the value in an existing row.

Answer (score 2):

select st_x(geom) as x, st_y(geom) as y from the_table;

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in my comment to your question it is not clear what you want to do.

Do you want to insert two new columns in your table that holds x and y values separately? That will look something like:

```
/*Add the two columns*/
ALTER TABLE the_table ADD COLUMN x float;
ALTER TABLE the_table ADD COLUMN y float;

/*put values in the new columns)*/
UPDATE the_table SET x=ST_X(geom), y=ST_Y(geom);
```

Or do you want a new table with the x and y in separate columns instead:

```
CREATE TABLE my_xy_table AS
SELECT ST_X(geom) as x, ST_y(geom) as y FROM the_table;
```

But if you want to insert new rows in the old table that instead of having a geometry datatype should have two columns of type float, then you will have problems. You can not mix rows with different data types in a table.

Comment: I'm inserting into the database...

Answer (score 1):

[ST_Y](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Y.html) and [ST_X](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_X.html)

```sql
alter table <myschema>.<mytable> add column x_coords_4326 float4;
update <myschema>.<mytable> as a set x_coords_4326 = st_x(st_transform(a.geom,4326));

alter table <myschema>.<mytable> add column y_coords_4326 float4;
update <myschema>.<mytable> as a set y_coords_4326 = st_y(st_transform(a.geom,4326));
```